# Best way to detect company in string

Tags: algorithm, string-comparison

I am importing data from different sources and need to compare the company names from this data with a list of defined and cleaned companies, what I have in my DB.

The problem is, that I become the companies in different ways and somethimes there are differet writing methods. For example I have as company "Google GbmH" in my DB. But I become from my sources names in the form: Google, Google Germany GmbH, Google Germany etc.

I need an algo, what can compare this strings and detect, that this is the company in my DB "Google GmbH".

What will be the best way to do this?

Comment: It's called Named Entity Recognition and is not an easy problem. I guess you could simplify the task by using some pattern matching though, since you have some canonical name.

Comment: If you can enumerate the variations, then just feed them all into your lookup function.  (But if it were that easy, you probably wouldn't be here.)

Comment: you need to write an algorithm specifically for your needs, once identified the different cases, we should be able very well. You can solve comparing strings or sequences with "contains" or "mid" depends on the language you choose.